# how to load div's child elements from another HTML file? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

```
<div id="transactions">
   <span>Money 1</span>
   <span>Money 2</span>
   <span>Money 3</span>
</div>
```

I have code something like this. I want load div's child elements to another HTML file without loading div. (focus is not loading spans, focus is loading div's child elements)

I tried

```
$(sometag).load(URL + '#transactions');
```

it loads outer div also and it crashes design.

Comment: You explicitly told the JavaScript to load the "*outer div also*", as for "*[crashing the] design*" what does that mean? Have you tried styling it with the appropriate CSS in the page you're loading it/them into?

Comment: @DavidThomas aah if I load that, my HTML structure changes and doesn't match with my css code

Answer (score 2):

You can connect with ajax to the URL. And then you can use jQuery selector.

Example

```
var URL = "https://example.com/path/to/page";

$.get(URL, function(data){

    var transactions = $("#transactions", data);
    console.log(transactions);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test that later when I am home. I have voted your answer